# Extract private key raw bytes from its serialized version

Tags: python, cryptography

I need to generate a private/public key pair with the `SECT163R2` curve (B-163).

For my application, I need them as raw bytes, without any header or protocol informations. The private key should theoretically be 24 bytes long and the public key 48 bytes.

However, I did not manage to find a way to extract those raw bytes using the `cryptography` module. I used the `private_bytes(encoding, format, encryption)` function, but I cannot use the `Raw` format.

The keys I get are way too long, whichever format I use and I don't know how to strip the metadatas from PKCS#8 for example.

Comment: If priv_key is an `cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec.EllipticCurvePrivateKey` then `priv_key.private_numbers().private_value` will return the private key as an int. You can then use `int.to_bytes()` to convert the int to bytes. A similar exercise with `cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec.EllipticCurvePublicNumbers` can be used to convert the x and y coordinates to bytes.

Comment: Note that you are clearly **NOT** heeding the warning for the module: *This is a “Hazardous Materials” module. You should ONLY use it if you’re 100% absolutely sure that you know what you’re doing*.